# remove pairs from nested dictionary that contain a character

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary in the following format, and I want to keep only *unit* items that have a *negative* *value*

```
dic = dict(({'a': [{'unit': 'x', 'value': '1', 'type':'int'},{'unit': '19', 'value':'-1', 'input':'man'},{'unit': 'y', 'value':'-2'}],
      'b': [{'unit':'b', 'value': '3', 'type':'int'},{'unit': 'g', 'value':'3'},{'unit': 'tol', 'value':'-12'}]}))
```

I have this code - where the out variable does print the intended part of the dictionary, but im having trouble appending it back to the correct key and outputting a complete dictionary. Also perhaps an inelegant way of selecting negative, values, is that I am simply selecting fields that contain a '-' in the value pair..

```
out=[]
for k, v in dic.items():
    for x in v:
        if '-' in x['value']:
            out=x
    dic[k].append(dict(out))
```

the expected dictionary would be like this

```
dict(({'a': [{'unit': '19', 'value':'-1', 'input':'man'},{'unit': 'y', 'value':'-2'}],
      'b': [{'unit': 'tol', 'value':'-12'}]}))
```

thanks for looking

Comment: In your desired result `out` is a list, in your code it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want negative numeric values, casting the `str` to `int`/`float` rather than checking for the `'-'` character in the string is more elegant.

```py
>>> new_dic = {}
>>> for key, val in dic.items():
        new_dic[key] = [entry for entry in val if int(entry['value']) < 0]

>>> # or as an equivalent one-liner:
>>> new_dic = {key: [entry for entry in val if int(entry['value']) < 0] for key, val in dic.items()}

>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(new_dic)
{'a': [{'input': 'man', 'unit': '19', 'value': '-1'},
       {'unit': 'y', 'value': '-2'}],
 'b': [{'unit': 'tol', 'value': '-12'}]}
```

Additionally we can clean up your initial dictionary definition. There's a whole lot of unnecessary stuff going on. There's no need to wrap everything in extra parentheses or use the `dict` constructor. Simply use the `{<def'n>}` construct directly:

```py
dic = {
    'a': [{'unit': 'x', 'value': '1', 'type':'int'},
          {'unit': '19', 'value':'-1', 'input':'man'},
          {'unit': 'y', 'value':'-2'}],
    'b': [{'unit':'b', 'value': '3', 'type':'int'},
          {'unit': 'g', 'value':'3'},
          {'unit': 'tol', 'value':'-12'}]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use comprehension for this

```
a = dict(({'a': [{'unit': 'x', 'value': '1', 'type':'int'},{'unit': '19', 'value':'-1', 'input':'man'},{'unit': 'y', 'value':'-2'}], 'b': [{'unit':'b', 'value': '3', 'type':'int'},{'unit': 'g', 'value':'3'},{'unit': 'tol', 'value':'-12'}]}))

b = {k : [x for x in v if '-' in x['value']] for k,v in a.items()}

# or if you want to replace the original dict then replace b by a

a = {k : [x for x in v if '-' in x['value']] for k,v in a.items()}
```